# How to force NSDocument isDocumentEdited YES immediately after pushing state to NSUndoManager

Tags: cocoa, nsdocument, nsundomanager

I'm using NSDocument in combination with its NSUndoManager.
I noticed there's a delay in setting the NSDocument updateChangeCount when pushing an undoable operation to the UndoManager:

```
[undoManager registerUndoWithTarget:self selector:@selector(applyUndoState:) object:state];
NSLog(@"Document.isEdited: %d", [self isDocumentEdited]);
```

This will show "0" if the document was not modified before this call.
Seems the undomanager calls updateChangeCount later some time after this method exits.
Is there a way to force the undomanager to update the document updateChangeCount ?
I could manually call

```
if (![self isDocumentEdited]) 
  [self updateChangeCount:NSChangeDone];
```

but I don't know if that would be safe in interaction with the undomanager.

Comment: Why do you need the edited state of the document at exactly this moment?

Comment: Because I want to commit changes in a modeless editor when the user clicks on a navigator treeview. The document needs to be saved immediately after this call, before the runloop proceeds into the next event. I have added the work around mentioned, and it seems to work OK,

Answer (score 2):

NSUndoManager groups undo events automatically until the end of the current event, where it closes the current group and processes it.

I’m not sure how your would work around this because I’m not sure why you want `isDocumentEdited` to change immediately.

Comment: The work around seems to work OK, I can see not problems in Undo/Redo, nor in Document needs saving state.